# Dell Latitude SupportAssist detected high system temperature

Tags: 14.04, dell, heat

My Dell Latitude 3560's SupportAssist detected high system temperature.

[image]

Is there anything I should be doing as a precautionary measure ?

```
$ uname -a
Linux anjanesh-Latitude-3560 3.13.0-117-generic #164-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 7 11:05:26 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Can you mention how frequently this happens? And can you associate this with any activity/applications running at the time?

Comment: This is the second time this has happened. Both on startup - not while using the laptop. I had shutdown normally too - not a hard shutdown.

Comment: Second out of how many times? Is this after a new kernel? Have you tried an older kernel? You really should try to be more informative.

Comment: I don't have much kernel experience. I just update the OS when it asks to.

Comment: Do you have any power management installed?  I use TLP in my dell, and have been having good results.  I would certainly follow the advice in the warning:  make sure that the vents on the computer are unobstructed, and check to see if the fans are pumping air through the system.

Comment: I guess no power management installed. My Dell laptop has been sitting at my desk like a desktop for almost a year. I don't travel with it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem on my Dell Inspiron Mini. After researching it on "Ask Ubuntu," I ran the 'top' command on the command line and found that a program named "BOINC" was causing my CPUs to run at 100% all the time. I disabled that program and now my laptop runs very cool. Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)